# Resource Group for file share not starting

Tags: pacemaker

I have a client that is trying to configure a file share for a 2 node cluster.  Running this command seems to fix it but as soon as we switch over, it stops again.  Any ideas?

[image: status]

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Please [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22222). Instead, copy/paste the text into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format it as code. Also, please [edit] and give us some context, we don't even know what operating system you are using, or exactly what you are trying to set up. What would success look like? What is the failure? What kind of file sharing are you configuring?

Answer (score 0):

Your symptoms overlap enough with one of my previous situations that I'll propose a solution.

- You have a 2-node cluster, as did I; one difference I see in your setup is that you have one of those nodes ("k03") in standby mode, which means that node won't be able to run the resource.
- You have a resource that won't start; `pcs status` shows that resource with a state of `Stopped`.
- The cluster does not have a fencing device; `pcs status` contains `No stonith devices and stonith-enabled is not false`

I discovered that I could force the resource to start with the `debug-start` option (e.g. `pcs resource debug-start hvrconfig_fs`), but the **better** solution in my case was to configure a fencing / stonith device. Once I did that, the resource(s) started on their own. I followed Red Hat's [Configuring and managing high availability clusters: Configuring fencing in a Red Hat High Availability cluster](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_high_availability_clusters/assembly_configuring-fencing-configuring-and-managing-high-availability-clusters) online documentation to set up a fencing resource.

Separately, I'd recommend bringing the other node ("k02") back into the cluster with `pcs node unstandby ...k02...` so that you have a failover target for the resource(s).